# cypress load a page chosen from the list

Tags: javascript, cypress

Right now i have 3 different websites that im testing and the same code works for all of them. But every time i have to manually change the URL for each website to test like:

```
it('Navigate to URL', function() {
        cy.visit('https://myurl.com')
})
```

and then change the URL to my other website etc.

Is it possible to choose the URL before the testing begins? So when i "start" the testing, it stops for a second for me to choose the URL, like have a dropdown menu of each url and when i click one then it chooses the one i chose and then loads the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer reached by @BrandoN is:

"So what i did. I made a new html, add my links there and added `cy.visit('./links.html')` instead of the URL. I also added `cy.pause()` at the start of the script because that allowes me to choose one of the links and then rest of the code runs on that page i chose. Not the best solution to my problem, but works for me atm :D"

Other things worth checking out: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Setting-a-global-baseUrl

Maybe you can set it through and environment variable: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#We-can-move-this-into-a-Cypress-environment-variable

To me it sounds like you are testing three identical pages after deployment? If so consider testing before deployment and having deployment as part of the pipeline.

If it's three different, but deceptively alike, projects, odds are that having three sets of tests is better, even if they are identical right now. But that's hard to tell for sure

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. 
I have three identical pages with different URLs. I just dont want to manually change the url every time. I can make three sets of tests, but if it is posseble to choose the URL at the start of the script then that would be better and i wouldnt need to make 3 tests. 
So the question is. Is it posseble for cypress to ask me which URL i want to use at the start of the test without changing the code itself?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but maybe through environment variables, I updated the answer with a link. Perhaps that can be useful? Then you should be able to make multiple run scripts in `package.json` and/or bash aliases

Comment: So what i did. I made a new html, add my links there and added `cy.visit('./links.html')` instead of the URL. I also added `cy.pause()` at the start of the script because that allowes me to choose one of the links and then rest of the code runs on that page i chose. Not the best solution to my problem, but works for me atm :D

Comment: Ah makes sense :) I added your solution to the answer (with due credit of course) :)